# dell vostro 1510 beep code - 1 long 2 shorts - Can´t find the reason related to that

Tags: motherboard, bios, dell-vostro

Can´t find the following beep code anywhere. I have changed the memory stick and nothing happened. This is the beep code I´m always getting:

1 long 2 shorts.

Would that be a memory or a video related problem?

P.S.: I couldn´t find the bios model of my vostro 1510 and also here where the beep code should be it is not there:

http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN143065

Comment: You didn't provide us model information on your Dell.  [The error indicates a problem with your video card.](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/the-complete-bios-beep-guide.95391/)

Comment: @Ramhound Actually I have. It´s a Dell Vostro 1510. This is the model. Am I wrong? And which bios does It has? I am unable to see as it not display anything and I could not find anywhere.

Comment: I aplogize.  *You didn't specifcy the model in the question itself.*  I don't read the title of a question more then once.

Comment: @Ramhound Its ok. But do you know which bios come with that vostro?

Comment: My knowlege is based on 20 years.  How I know something cannot be identified.